# What causing locales issue in debian?

Tags: debian, locale

My question is not about how to fix it, but about what causing perl warning in debian after doing `apt-get install`. I found the easiest way to fix this issue is:

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
locale-gen
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

After doing that, `apt-get install --reinstall` not throwing warning about locale unset anymore.

What I want to know is what is causing this issue? I happens after fresh install. I'm doing installation alot in virtual box for testing purpose. And every install have this issue. And, the issue is back after reboot? It happens on ubuntu too.

So, can anyone tell me what is causing locale issue?

Comment: I see this problem reported fairly often.  I think you should clarify that you aren't looking for a solution to the perl locale warning (`dpkg-reconfigure locales` evidently works) but for an explanation of why it has to be done in the first place.

Comment: Yes it works. And the issue will come back randomly. I googled, and I can only find solutions without any explanation what is causing this and how this issue can affect the system.

Comment: @BagolDaplun are you running testing or unstable? I believe this is often a result of perl transitions in the non-stable branches.

Comment: It's stable release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's known that Perl complains loudly on starting up when it fails to find the compiled locale data in `/usr/lib/locale/.../` or `/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive` for the locale you specify in the environment variables (`LANG` and others).  It's easily reproducible like this:

```
$ LANG=xyz perl /dev/null
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_PAPER = "ja_JP.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "ja_JP.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "ja_JP.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "ja_JP.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "ja_JP.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "ja_JP.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "ja_JP.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "ja_JP.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "ja_JP.UTF-8",
    LANG = "xyz"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

So basically you should check available locales in the system and your locale settings in the environment variables when you see warnings above.

You can use `locale -a` to see all available locales, or `localedef` to list/add/delete compiled locales in `locale-archive`.

```
$ localedef --list-archive
en_US.utf8
ja_JP
ja_JP.eucjp
ja_JP.ujis
ja_JP.utf8
japanese
japanese.euc
```

`locale-gen` is a Debian specific wrapper script for `localedef` with config file `/etc/locale.gen`.  `dpkg-reconfigure locales` updates `/etc/locale.gen` then just calls `locale-gen`.

Note that Ubuntu has the same command `locale-gen`, but its implementation seems quite different than Debian.  It sees `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/` for config and `dpkg-reconfigure locales` has no effect on Ubuntu.  See also [the community wiki instruction](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale).

Locale related variables are set in your environment by various programs explicitly or implicitly.  They would usually be initialized by `pam_env.so` with `/etc/default/locale` or `~/.pam_environment` in the beginning of  the session.  More notably `ssh` will automatically send local locale settings to remote host sessions per default in Debian/Ubuntu.
You can see the following line in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, which is mentioned in `ssh_config` manual page.

```
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

Comment: I understand it know after read your last paragraph, `Locale related ...` . May be it's because I login via ssh to debian VM. One more question, is it alter the default configuration in the machine that I login to?

Comment: In the SSH session, environment variables seem to get updated in the following order: 1) `SendEnv` by SSH, 2) `libpam_env.so` by PAM, 3) shell's start up scripts (`.profile` `.bashrc` etc.).  You have enough knowledge to find the cause of the problem for yourself when you encounter it in the next time.  Good luck!