# "bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale" - misleading? What does it mean?

Tags: bash, locale

I want to understand how locales work. In particular I've read ["-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294845/bash-warning-setlocale-lc-all-cannot-change-locale-en-us-utf-8) and https://askubuntu.com/questions/114759/warning-setlocale-lc-all-cannot-change-locale

On my Linux Mint I did `locale-gen fr_FR.*`, after that `LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8` outputs "bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (fr_FR.UTF-8)". However `locale` after that shows "LC_NAME=fr_FR.UTF-8", etc., so locale variables are changed. Why write "cannot change locale"?

I did `LC_NAME=qq_QQ.UTF-8` (non-existent? locale) and the result is same - warning, `locale` output updated.

I've noted there is no warning only in case new assignment was already generated before that bash terminal is started. In line with that `bash -c "LC_NAME=fr_FR.UTF-8"` produced no warning.

Command from https://askubuntu.com/questions/114759/warning-setlocale-lc-all-cannot-change-locale `sudo update-locale LANG=fr_FR` did not get rid of the warning.

I have suspicion current bash session has hold of `/etc/defaults/locale` and other files so `locale-gen` has no effect on that. Correct? `strace` output is (yet) too complex for me to read, I only have not found `/etc/defaults/locale` in it.

Added:

System Linux Mint 20.2 (Ubuntu based). I've used `locale-gen name.*` IIRC cause I've read that line somewhere and also output showed it is exactly locales for `name` were `done`. Now upon reading the answer and man page of `locale-gen` I've tried to comment out name.* in `/etc/locale.gen`, run `sudo locale-gen`, then un-comment `name.UTF-8` back and run `sudo locale-gen` again. The result is same as before when running `locale-gen name.*`

Answer (score 10):

Your warning suggests that the locales you are requesting have not actually been compiled. So, you should use:

```bash
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

to select the locales to compile.

Alternatively, just edit the file:

```
/etc/locale.gen
```

and uncomment the locales you want, then run:

```bash
sudo locale-gen
```

to generate them.

**What are the locale variables?**

The locale environment variables are just regular environment variables that have been assigned a special meaning by the C library (`glibc`). Specifically, those variables will be used when a program requests activation of localization support by calling `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` or similar. At that point, the C library will load the appropriate localization settings from `/usr/lib/locale/`.

These localization settings are pre-compiled by the `localedef` utility using the locale source data in `/usr/share/locale`. In Debian, Ubuntu and related distributions, `localedef` is called by `locale-gen`.

**Why `locale-gen fr_FR.*` does not work**

`locale-gen` does not take any arguments from the command line. It only reads `/etc/locale.gen` to determine which locale(s) to generate. So depending on which locales are uncommented in your `/etc/locale.gen` file, your `locale-gen fr_FR.*`command may have had no desired effect.

The `update-locale` command is just a tool for package maintainer scripts to update the system-wide default locale environment variable settings in `/etc/default/locale`. It has no effect at all on which locales are actually going to be compiled.

Comment: Thanks for explaining mystery of `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales `. However your last paragraph (un-commenting name.UTF-8; `locale-gen`) is not working - warning is there for `LC_NAME=name.UTF-8`. And not there when run via `bash -c`. Please see "Added" to the question.